# Unable to connect to Informix database server on a Virtual Box Linux environment from Genero Studio on a Mac

Tags: macos, database-connection, virtualbox, informix, genero

I am trying to connect to my Informix database server that I set up on my Virtual Box Linux environment. I am using Genero Studio on a macOS system to try to connect.

However, I'm unable to make a successful connection.

I already set up the following:

```
Sqlhosts file  
Informix Server- INFORMIXSERVERNAME
Informix Dir -   INFORMIXDIR
```

The error I get when trying to connect:

```
Connection to database failed:
SQL: CONNECT TO "acp@ol_informix1410_1+driver='dbmifx'" AS "fgldbsch" USER "staggers" USING "***"
 | 4gl source      : fgldbslib.4gl line=887
 | loading driver  : [/Applications/Genero Studio 3.20.07-167010.app/fgl/dbdrivers/dbmifx]
 | Dynamic linker error: [dlopen(/Applications/Genero Studio 3.20.07-167010.app/fgl/dbdrivers/dbmifx.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: @rpath/isqls09b.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/Genero Studio 3.20.07-167010.app/fgl/dbdrivers/dbmifx_9.dylib
  Reason: image not found]...
Connection to database 'acp@ol_informix1410_1' failed.
      -6366: Could not load database driver dbmifx. Set FGLSQLDEBUG to get more details.
```